# FullCalendar - Hide days in week labels

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) (2.3.1) with the [ui-calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) (0.8.1) AngularJS directive. I need to hide the column headers that contain the days of the week (Sun, Mon, Tues, etc.). I can see where the calendar header can be configured (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/), but this doesn't include the headers for each column in the calendar, which contains the day of week labels.

I've been combing the docs, but can't find a way to toggle this. Is it possible to hide the day of week labels through a configuration parameter in FullCalendar itself, or perhaps in the ui-calendar directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your $scope.uiConfig.calendar object you can specify custom "Day" names. So if you wanted to some of them but not all of them or any combination in between you could do it like this.

```
$scope.uiConfig = {calendar:{ dayNames: ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''] } };
```

OR

```
$scope.uiConfig = {calendar:{ dayNames: ['Su', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'Sa'] } };
```

You can put whatever you want in there, allowing you to hide/show day names without editing the CSS.

Comment: I like the configuration solution, this worked great for me. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me too. Awesome, dude!

Answer (score 0):

All days cells ('Mon', 'Tue' etc..) belong to class 'fc-day-header' in FullCalendar. So, if all you want is to hide that header, you can do it like this : `$('.fc-day-header').hide();`

This should work for what you need.